# Querying Database for specific Datetime (No seconds or milliseconds)

Tags: mysql, datetime

Hey there I'm trying to query the my SQL ser database for a certain datetime. 
The dates are saved to the database in this format

2016-04-12 01:50:21.907

What I am trying to do is to check that this format matches:

2016-04-12 01:50

so the query would be something like:

```
Select *
FROM Appointments
WHERE startdate.format = inputdate.format;
```

so far i cannot find any format that allows me to do this
Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: why you are using `==` ?

Comment: its just an example didnt mean to enter two = in

Comment: SUBSTR is also an option if you are doing string comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Select *
FROM Appointments
WHERE LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,startdate,20),LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR,startdate,20))-3) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,inputdate,20),LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR,inputdate,20))-3);
```

Comment: Would this work : `Select *
FROM Appointments
WHERE LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,startdate,20),LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR,startdate,20))-3) = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,inputdate,20),LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR,inputdate,20))-3);`

Comment: if `inputdate` is also coulmn or variable then it it right, Updated Ans

Answer (score 1):

Use DATE_FORMAT

```
Select *
FROM Appointments
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(startdate.format, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i') = '2016-04-12 01:50'
```